# Dealing with multirelations (of arity ~10)

Tags: alloy

I have a model with a sig similar to this one:

```
sig State {
  ps: set P,
  cs: set C,
  o: set C -> set P,
  m: set M
}
```

And predicates like this, dealing with two `State`s:

```
pred my_pred [s, s': State] {
  ...
}
```

I'm trying to create a parameterized version of my model, where I don't have a `State` sig, and instead I pass those fields around explicitly in functions and predicates. That would mean having predicates that look something like

```
pred my_pred [(M -> P -> C -> (C -> P)) ->
              (M -> P -> C -> (C -> P))] {
  ...
}
```

My question is, how can one easily deal with relations of relatively large arity, such as the one in `my_pred`? For instance, I was trying to use `dom` from `util/relation`, but `dom` is defined over a binary relation, and unfortunately it seems that alloy sees this

```
  (M -> P -> C -> (C -> P))
  ->
  (M -> P -> C -> (C -> P))
```

as a relation of arity 10 rather than 2; meaning that the parenthesizing is ignored. So using `dom` would return something of type `M`, rather than of the desired type of `(M -> P -> C -> (C -> P))`.

Also on a related note, I was wondering if/how one could use the transitive closure operators on relations like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's generally bad practice to have relations of arity greater than 3.

Why don't you simply declare your predicate as follows :

```
pred my_pred [m,m':M , ps,ps':P , cs,cs':C , o,o':(C -> P)] {
  ...
}
```