# alloy translation limitations: arity of relations

Tags: alloy

We're getting the following error message in the Alloy Analyzer:

Translation capacity exceeded.
In this scope, universe contains 9 atoms
and relations of arity 10 cannot be represented.

Since two different factors are mentioned here: #atoms and arity of relation, what exactly in the limitation and 
how hard coded into the tool is this limit?  I recognize that stylistically relations of smaller arity are preferable.

We are autogenerating Alloy code in a manner where it is most efficient if we have relations of high arity rather than using predicates with multiple arguments.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dealing with multirelations (of arity ~10)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51997723/dealing-with-multirelations-of-arity-10)

Comment: The question is related, but we are autogenerating Alloy code.

Comment: You could change the way you generate code to use the predicate approach proposed in the answer of the related question. 
If such lenghty relation is not used to check a specific property but to be referenced multiple times elsewhere, you could also consider defining it with a let expression.

Comment: We have a number of recursive functional relationships, where the function returns a relation.  If we model this as a predicate then we have to add a number of quantifiers, which detracts from the performance.  I was hoping to get a better understanding of how the # of atoms and arity of relations are connected with respect to this limitation and how hard-coded the limitation is into the Alloy code base because we could compile a version of Alloy with a higher limit.

Comment: This is the answer you seek. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387155/type-error-has-occured-translation-capacity-exceeded.  Not sure this limitation can easily be disposed of

Answer (score 0):

If you have 9 atoms in your universe, how could you ever have a relation with arity 10? (Assuming each column is a different type.)

You can in Alloy always increase the number of atoms in the universe with the scope defined on the `run` statement. However, an arity of ten sounds a bit unreasonable.

Comment: With a set A, I can have a relation A->A->A->A->etc.|
How hard coded is the limit of arity 10?

Comment: answer to how is the limit "hardcoded" is here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387155/type-error-has-occured-translation-capacity-exceeded

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you're translating in the best way. An arity of this size is huge. You can often break a relation up using new sigs. For example, if you have a relation

```
r: A -> B -> C
```

you might be able to break it into

```
r1: A -> BC
b: BC -> B
c: BC -> C
```